# Pointers and Indexes in Intel 8086 Assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly, intel, indexing, x86-16

I have a pointer to an array, DI.

Is it possible to go to the value pointed to by both DI and another pointer?

e.g:

```
mov bl,1           
mov bh,10
inc [di+bl]
inc [di+bh]
```

And, on a related note,  is there a single line opcode to swap the values of two registers? (In my case, BX and BP?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 16-bit programs, the only supported addressing forms are:

```
[BX+SI]
[BX+DI]
[BP+SI]
[BP+DI]
[SI]
[DI]
[BP]
[BX]
```

Each of these may include either an 8- or 16-bit constant displacement.

(Source: [Intel Developer's Manual volume 2A](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/), page 38)

The problem with the example provided is that `bl` and `bh` are eight-bit registers and cannot be used as the base pointer. However, if you set `bx` to the desired value then `inc [di+bx]` (with a suitable size specifier for the pointer) is valid.

---

As for swapping "the high and low bits of a register," [J-16 SDiZ's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384346/pointers-and-indexes-in-intel-8086-assembly/3384358#3384358) suggestion of `ror bx, 8` is fine for exchanging `bl` and `bh` (and IIRC, it is the optimal way to do so). However, if you want to exchange bit 0 of (say) `bl` with bit 7 of `bl`, you'll need more logic than that.

Comment: Is there a way to swap two registers then? Say, BX and BP?

Comment: The `XCHG` instruction (eg. `XCHG BX, BP`). The source again is the Intel manual linked in my answer (actually volume 2B). I'd recommend having those handy when doing assembly development. They still have the 16-bit information as well, along with 32-bit, 64-bit and all the other extensions since.

Answer (score 1):

DI is not a pointer, it is an index.

You can you `ROR BX, 8` to rotate a lower/higher byte of a register.