# stack pointer in assembly level programming

Tags: x86

I have just started learning assembly level programming.I have read that the stack pointer points to the top of the stack in the stack segment. 
Is it possible for a user to change the value stored in the stack pointer of 8086?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384346/pointers-and-indexes-in-intel-8086-assembly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can change the stack pointer (`sp`/`esp`/`rsp` for 16/32/64 bits, respectively) implicitly with eg. `push`, `pop`, `call` or `return`, or explicitly the same way you would change any other general-purpose register.

In fact, if you disassemble a program, you will often find something like `sub esp, 4` (intel syntax) near the beginning of functions. It is used to reserve space (4 bytes in this case) on the stack for local variables in the function.